# minimising quadratic function subject to integer solutions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, integer-programming, quadratic-programming

I would appreciate if one could help me to solve this problem.

I have a bivariate quadratic function:
$$ f(a_1,a_2)=(1-u_1^2)a_1^2 +(1-u_2^2)a_2^2 -2u_1u_2a_1a_2 $$
where $u_1^2+u_2^2=1$ and $a_1$ and $a_2$ are unknowns. In order to minimise this function I take the partial derivate and I find that it has its minimum on a line (instead of a point). I have derived the line as 
$$a_1=\frac{u_1}{u_2}a_2$$
and I have attached a figure showing this function and its minimum line.

My question is I am interested in finding the integer values for $a_1$ and $a_2$subject to $a_1^2+a_2^2<m$ constraint. Considering that I know the minimum line equation, is there any way to find integer values for $a_1$ and $a_2$?

any hint is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: $(0,0)$ works. If the ratio $u_2/u_1$ is irrational, that is it. If the ratio is rational, for example $u_1 = \frac{3}{5}, $ $u_2 = \frac{4}{5}, $ you do get other integer points.

Comment: Thank you Will for the answer, and sorry I was not clear in the question. I am looking for a nonzero point.

Comment: there are nonzero integer points if and only if $u_2/u_1$ is rational. This need no t require them separately rational, for example $u_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt {10}}$ $u_2 = \frac{3}{\sqrt {10}}$

Answer (score 1):

$$a_1=\frac{u_1}{u_2}a_2$$
My question is I am interested in finding the integer values for $a_1$ and $a_2$subject to $a_1^2+a_2^2<m$ constraint.

If $u_1/u_2$ is irrational, there are no nonzero integer solutions. How could there be? it would be 
$$ \frac{a_1}{a_2} = \frac{u_1}{u_2},  $$
rational equal to irrational. Impossible.

On the other hand, it is possible for $u_1/ u_2$ to be rational with $u_1^2 + u_2^2 = 1.$ I gave the examples $\left( \frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5} \right),$ then $\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt {10}}, \frac{3}{\sqrt {10}} \right).$ If so, write, in lowest terms,
$$ \frac{p}{q} = \frac{u_1}{u_2},  $$
with integers $p,q,$ also $q > 0$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1.$ Your line becomes 
$$a_1=\frac{p}{q}a_2,$$ or $$ \frac{p}{q} = \frac{a_1}{a_2}.  $$

The integer points on the line are
$$ \ldots (-3p,-3q), (-2p, -2q); (-p,-q);  (0,0); (p,q); (2p,2q); (3p,3q); \ldots  $$
If $p^2 + q^2 \geq m,$ only he origin satisfies your constraint. If $p^2 + q^2 < m,$ some of these nonzero points satisfy the constraint.